# Python isnan - TypeError: Not implemented for this type

Tags: regex, file, python-2.7, numpy, nan

I have a list like this:

```
 - 1 21      84.0104      
 -  2 22      81.9372      
 -  3 23          NaN      
 - 4 00          NaN          
 -  5 01      78.7023      
 -  6 02      80.0526
```

In my code I tried to replace all NaN's with zero. So I used Numpy isnan:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from numpy import isnan

filename = "dataset"
file = open(filename)

data = []
for line in file:
    data.append(line.strip('\n').strip('\t').split(' '))
NaNs = np.isnan(data)                                                
data[NaNs] = 0
```

But this doesn't work for me and I get the Error-Message:

"NaNs = np.isnan(data)
TypeError: Not implemented for this type"

I also tried to integrate the module pandas with:

```
import pandas as pd
```

But this doesn't work for me either. I only get an "ImportError: No module named pandas". Can anybody help me to understand and solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The `No module named pandas` message means you don't have the pandas package installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data coming in is a string, which it looks like it is, you could probably just use:

`line.replace("NaN", "0")`

This should replace all `NaN` with a `0`.

Comment: When I use this my NaNs will be deleted from the list, but strange to say I do not have the zeros either in the list . I loose the lines and get other errors because I need the exactly line length.

Comment: try adding the `.replace` after the `.strip('\t')` before the `.split` in your data append.